# fancybox how to disable all shortcut keys?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Here is `fancybox` code :

```
$.fancybox({
   'titleShow': false,
   'width': '100%',
   'height': '100%',
   'href': url,
   'type': 'iframe',
   'keys' : {}//I am emptying key param values, but still shortcuts are working
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a guess, so should go as a comment - but I need the layout of an answer. Let me know if this doesn't work so I can delete.]

Have you tried overwriting the keys object with children? Something like

```
{
    next : {
        0 : 'left'
    },
    prev : {
        0  : 'right'
    },
    close  : [0],
    play   : [0],
    toggle : [0]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, This works perfectly fin, Thank you very much

Comment: Nice. Glad it worked - I'll leave the answer in case others need it.